# Tachometer air core meter - how does it operate?

Tags: automotive, 12v, gauge

This is a question from a total noob, out of pure curiosity.
I've been tinkering with my bike's instrument panel and took it apart -

I found out that this sin-cos marking is the base of the air core gauge.

I've seen the wiki explanation on how it works, sin current and cos current give a certain trigonometric value and swoop the needle to that position.

What I don't get it how the signal is measured.

I looked at the diagram, found the wire that goes from cluster connector to the ECU, and measured with voltmeter with bike running. It gave about 8.5V but it would jump to 9V with a bit of throttle applied.

Is this the correct way to interpret how it works, it gets voltage from ECU to the coil? How does it separate cos and sin signal to get the needle angle?

Some tutorials online suggest that the only right way to test the meter is with multimeter + peak voltage adapter.

[image]

Comment: How's it look on an oscilloscope? It's likely a high frequency signal (probably with a frequency dependent on speed, as that's how most rotary encoders work).

Comment: I don't have the scope unfortunately, I just measured Vdc on the connector input where tacho's pin goes and leads to the ECU according to the diagram. I also tried switching the multimeter to amps and the reading while bike idling was around 0.3A ... but yeah it might be that it's not pure simple voltage that goes into the coil under the needle.

Comment: You do have an oscilloscope - the sound card in your PC. Google 'soundcard oscilloscope' for the hardware and software interface. Even better if you have a laptop.

Answer (score 2):

A permanent magnet is affixed to the shaft and there are two coils at 90 degrees from each other, the current ratio between the two coils should be the sin and cos of the desired angle.

Think of a vector- the length is not so important but the angle is important. Photo from [here](https://newvintageusallc.mybigcommerce.com/blog/gauge-meters-movements-motors-and-functions/):

[image]

Ideally, the needle will rotate to an angle \$\theta = tan^{-1}(i_x/i_y)\$ where ix and iy are the currents through the coils.

There are a number of ICs designed for driving automotive air-core gauge movements.

The voltage across each coil (not to ground) will give you a rough idea of the current, but the copper resistance varies with temperature and one coil will not be the same resistance as the other (same number of turns, but different resistance, since they can't occupy the same space).  If you add a resistor in series with each coil (an ohm or two) you should be able to read the currents accurately with a multimeter on the 200mV range.

Comment: Make sense to measure the coils when its in place :D I presume I would get different wavelengths depending on the throttle, if I had a scope and measured the connector pin where the tacho connects to?

Comment: @Varonne It's DC, or averages out to DC. The driver chips I've seen datasheets for just pump constant current DC through the coils with a linear amplifier.

Comment: Of course you can't tell *for sure* if you need to use an oscilloscope without having an oscilloscope.

Comment: Just looking to learn, trying to decipher how it works - or how to read into the way it works. If the needle jumps on throttle I'm trying to get my head around how would I measure those values and see them change as the engine revs up :D learning practice nothing more

Comment: To 'old' way was to sense the ignition coil signal and by analog or digital means this would get converted to a voltage/current for the meter. RPM would be measured as a frequency, not a varying voltage. Newer bikes might just get the rpm value from the CAN bus.